# 'cd ~' bring me to /root and not /home/myUsername

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When i try to go to my home directory by doing:

```
cd ~
```

It brings me to /root how can I change it to /home/myUsername ?

Comment: `cd` - alone brings you to your home directory. Can you not just execute that command? Oh, unless you are wanting to append a path onto your home directory.

Comment: It also brings me to /root

Comment: Root's home directory is usually `/root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your env paramater `$HOME`
When you do `cd ~` actually you are executing `cd $HOME`